# Linear Partitioning, Perfect Image Gallery

Tags: javascript, image, image-gallery, image-scaling

Has anybody seen this page before, from Chromatic.io?

http://www.chromatic.io/FQrLQsb

Their Gallery is perfect. I want to achieve the same thing. I largely have now, using their linear-partition.js file which is available on GitHub.

Johannes Treitz wrote a blog post about it here:

https://www.crispymtn.com/stories/the-algorithm-for-a-perfectly-balanced-photo-gallery

I have the images partitioning perfectly. The weights it gives to each image is also perfect. I have been able to test the values by using exactly the same markup as chromatic, and the same raw images. By switching between my window and theirs, I can see that the partition values are identical.

*The resulting page shows that my images are ever so slightly too large, as the last image in the row is dropping down to the next line and causes a butterfly effect further down the gallery whereby it looks awful.*

However, where I do `width / height` to calculate the aspect ratio of an image, Chromatic.io are quite clearly doing something else. An image of **531 x 800** yields an aspect ratio of **0.66375**. Whereas they are calculating aspect ratio server side, and they are getting **0.6645454545454546**. I cannot fathom how they are arriving at this number. What are they adding to their algorithm to get this number?

The same applies for their landscape images **800 x 531**. The aspect ratio I get is different to theirs, and what's more, they are getting different aspect ratios, (+- 0.002 either way), and yet ALL of their landscape images are the same.

I apologise for this rather lengthy code bite, but it may be that I am doing something wrong, so for anybody who knows how this works, here it is:

```
$(window).load(function () {

    var p = $('.photo');
    $(p).each(function ()
    {
        var h = $(this).find("img").height();
        var w = $(this).find("img").width();
        $(this).attr({ 'data-aspect-ratio': w / h });
    });

    var photos = p.toArray();
    var viewport = $('.images').width();
    var ideal_height = parseInt( $(window).height() / 2 );
    var summed_width = photos.reduce(function(sum, img)
    {
        return sum += $(img).data('aspect-ratio') * ideal_height;
    }, 0);
    var rows = Math.round( summed_width / viewport );

    var weights = photos.map(function (img) {
        return parseInt($(img).data('aspect-ratio') * 100);
    });
    var partition = linear_partition(weights, rows);

    var index = 0;
    for( var i in partition )
    {
        var summed_ratios;
        row_buffer = [];

        for( var j = 0; j < partition[i].length; j++ )
        {
            row_buffer.push(photos[index++])
        }

        summed_ratios = row_buffer.reduce(function (sum, img)
        {
            return sum += $(img).data('aspect-ratio');
        }, 0);

        for( var j = 0; j < row_buffer.length; j++ )
        {
            var img = row_buffer[j];
            $(img).width( parseInt(viewport / summed_ratios * $(img).data("aspect-ratio")) );
            $(img).height( parseInt(viewport / summed_ratios) );
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Maybe a small margin is considered as a part of the image on the server side?

Comment: I tried fiddling the numbers 532,530 or 801,799 etc and no number came close. It's like they're adding a fraction on or something. It's bugging me because what they have results in a working grid. It seems odd that this algorithm needs a constant offset to work.

Comment: There is some rounding involved. Did you read [the solution](https://www.crispymtn.com/stories/the-algorithm-for-a-perfectly-balanced-photo-gallery)?

Comment: var rows = Math.round( summed_width / viewport ); I'm already rounding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. It was very simple in fact. The algorithm and code was spot on. It turns out the images had a margin of 2px on all sides which the code was taking in to account. This meant the width of each image was 4px out and caused an overflow. To get around this I simply did the following:

```
},0);......]

    for( var j = 0; j < row_buffer.length; j++ )
    {
        var img = row_buffer[j];
        $(img).width( parseInt(viewport / summed_ratios * $(im
        g).data("aspect-ratio")) - <get_image_margin> );

        $(img).height( parseInt(viewport / summed_ratios) );

    }
```

By retrieving the margin the CSS had assigned to each image and removing it from the calculated width, everything worked just fine :)